# Controller support for Xbox one in Windows UWP

Tags: c#, xbox, uwp, xinput, xbox-one

I am wondering how I am supposed to handle input for UWP apps targeting Xbox One. I have noticed DirectInput, but I see two issues with it for my use cases:

1. From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee417001(v=vs.85).aspx), it only seems to support Xbox 360 controllers

   > XInput is an API that allows applications to receive input from the Xbox 360 Controller for Windows. Controller rumble effects and voice input and output are supported.
2. DirectX and all of its API's (Direct2d, Direct3D, Xinput, etc...) are only supported on C / C++. That means even if Xinput supported Xbox one controllers, I could not use C# or JavaScript to develop truly universal apps.

What options do I have (at least as far as C# is concerned) for supporting Xbox One controller support on a Windows UWP app?

Comment: Here is a running sample of a UWP app using Windows.Gaming.Input https://github.com/tiagonmas/GamepadUWP

Comment: Why do you use var for the controller and reading objects?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look at the [Windows.Gaming.Input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.gaming.input.aspx) namespace. Its [GamePad](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.gaming.input.gamepad.aspx) class is in the Universal API contract and available on all device families and languages.

Comment: I looked at this API and I will edit my question with example code

Comment: I wish the UWP SDK reference has more examples :/

Answer (score 4):

To back @Rob Caplan - MSFT with a source, this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2014/09/05/directx-tool-kit-now-with-gamepads.aspx) from the Microsoft Developer Network states:

> Windows 10: There is a new WinRT API in the **Windows.Gaming.Input** namespace for universal Windows apps. This API **supports both the Xbox 360 Common Controller and the Xbox One controller**, including access to the left/right trigger motors. The latest version of **GamePad is implemented using this new API when built for Windows 10**. Note that existing XInput-based Windows Store applications can link against xinputuap.lib which is an adapter for the new API for universal Windows apps--this adapter does not exist headset audio either.

Answer (score 0):

> DirectX and all of its API's (Direct2d, Direct3D, Xinput, etc...) are only supported on C / C++

Only natively supported, yes, but implementing DirectInput from C# is trivial using [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/)
However, DirectInput is not much use for reading XB controllers as the trigger axes are merged into one, and it's impossible to differentiate between no triggers held and both triggers held.