# Access joystick controls from visual studio 2015 in C#

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2015, joystick

I was hoping to be 'using Windows.Gaming' namespace but I don't see it listed in my Visual Studio 2015 edition.  I don't really even see a UWP project choice in the list of project templates. I tried the 'Blank App (Universal Windows 8.1)' template but autocomplete does NOT list a 'Windows.Gaming' namespace when I attempt to use it from a C# source file.

Maybe it just isn't supported in VS2015?

If so, how to access joystick controls from C# in VS2015? Is it possible?

I am aware of slimDX and sharpDX and may resort to one of those but is it possible with just the Windows 10 SDK and VS2015 to access a joystick controller?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36694777/how-do-i-reference-the-windows-gaming-input-namespace#comment61030454_36694777

Comment: I bet that is the problem. Thank you. I will try it out shortly.  I had read that question by the way but missed the solution as it was buried in the comments I guess.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I reference the Windows.Gaming.Input namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36694777/how-do-i-reference-the-windows-gaming-input-namespace)