# How Do I Access Windows.Gaming.Input in a Non-UWP C# Project?

Tags: c#, windows, input, uwp

I've seen some examples of using Windows.Gaming.Input in C++ console apps but is there a way to access it in a non-UWP C# project as well?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6):

I've managed to do this by doing the following:

1. Make sure VisualStudio is not running.
2. Open your project `*.csproj` file in a text editor, e.g. notepad.
3. Add `<TargetPlatformVersion>10.0</TargetPlatformVersion>` to the `*.csproj` file. You can put it after the `<TargetFrameworkVersion/>` entry.
   **Note**: In .NET 6+, the tag names are now: `<TargetPlatform>` and `<TargetFramework>`.
4. Open you project in Visual Studio.
5. Add the `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime` reference (I used v4.7.0, newest stable version at the time) with nuget, or manually browse for the DLL file on your system.
6. In Solution/Project Explorer, right-click References -> Add Reference...
7. You should be able to see "Universal Windows" on the side as an option now.
8. Add the `Windows.Gaming` reference.
9. In your `*.cs` files, you'll want to use the reference with `using Windows.Gaming.Input;`. If the reference is not found, try including it outside the namespace. Or you can also try `using global::Windows.Gaming.Input;` instead.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks for the tips, worked on Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: To work with Gamepads, you'll also need to add the System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime otherwise it won't be possible to subscribe and unsubscribe to the events.

Comment: I can't see "Universal Windows". This is how my .csproj file looks:
```c#
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
   <PropertyGroup>
      <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
      <TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework>
      <TargetPlatformVersion>10.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
      <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
      <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
      <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
   </PropertyGroup>
   <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime" Version="4.7.0" />
   </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```
P.S: Formatting didn't go well

Comment: This does not work. You won't have "Universal Windows" on the left as suggested, so either something has changed or this method has broke in recent .net6+

Comment: @viion The method has changed for .net6... They change the tag names in the new csproj format: `<TargetFramework>` and `<TargetPlatform>`. Updated answer, thanks.

Comment: @JoeDF any ideas for Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 The "Universal Windows" does not appear. I was trying to achieve a similar thing for Game Development Kit (GDK), see: https://mega.nz/file/4sYwhAxJ#TicrsfG6eafHvArVjms4JFIr14J8wBFLWihh_aIceiEMicrosoft

Comment: I have not used GDK before...  maybe you can try adding `<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Windows.Gaming" />
    <Reference Include="WindowsBase" />
  </ItemGroup>`

Answer (score 0):

> but is there a way to access it in C# with UWP as well?

Sure, you could access `Windows.Gaming.Input` with C# within UWP platform. For example,

```
var controllers = RawGameController.RawGameControllers;
 foreach (var item in controllers)
 {
    var name =  item.DisplayName;
 }
```

Unfortunately, there is not c# project could be referred, if you do want to c# project, please feel free post your requirement with Windows Feed Backhub app.