# Xbox One Controller UWP App

Tags: javascript, c#, uwp, gamepad, xbox-one

I have been trying to make an Xbox One controller interact with a UWP application and have looked into the Gamepad class (based on the suggestions mentioned in the comments - [Controller support for Xbox one in Windows UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977767/controller-support-for-xbox-one-in-windows-uwp)).
I have 2 issues:

1) Gamepad.Gamepads.Count returns 0 for me even when I have my Xbox One controller switched on while the application is running on Xbox.

2) I do not know, how exactly can I assess when the A, B, X and Y buttons are pressed and also access the coordinates of the Left and Right Thumbsticks.

Any guidance about the 2 points mentioned above, would be very helpful for me. 
Thanks!

Edit: I have been getting an exception of type "System.InvalidOperationException" in System.Linq.dll when I use Gamepad.Gamepads.First() in the MainPage method in MainPage.xaml.cs

Comment: If you're building a UWP app, you should get default controller support for free. Are you trying to customize how the controller buttons are handled?

Comment: Yes I am. Hence I was trying to figure out how to access the thumbstick coordinates and also how to assess when a particular button is pressed.

Comment: I am getting an exception of type "System.InvalidOperationExeption" in System.Linq.dll when I try to use the Gamepad class in the MainPage method in MainPage.xaml.cs