# Xbox One Controller Thumbstick Coordinates (in UWP app)

Tags: c#, uwp, xbox, gamepad

How can I access the coordinates of the two Xbox One thumbsticks in a UWP application? Also, how can I detect when the X, Y, A and B buttons are pressed?

Edit: I have been getting an exception of type "System.InvalidOperationException" in System.Linq.dll when I use Gamepad.Gamepads.First() in the MainPage method in MainPage.xaml.cs

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977767/controller-support-for-xbox-one-in-windows-uwp

Comment: Try getting `Gamepad.Gamepads.First()` after a delay of 3 seconds or so.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at [gaming technologies for UWP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt282476.aspx) and in particular [Windows.Gaming.Input API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.gaming.input.aspx).

In short: after you get access to your gamepad:

```
 var controller = Gamepad.Gamepads.First();
```

You start reading [`GamepadReadings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.gaming.input.gamepadreading.aspx) from it:

```
 var reading = controller.GetCurrentReading();
```

Each reading contains data on thumbsticks, triggers and buttons.

```
 var leftThumbstickX = reading.LeftThumbstickX;
 var aButton = (reading.Buttons & GamepadButtons.A);
```

Comment: Gamepad.Gamepads.Count returns 0 for me even when I have my Xbox One controller switched on while the application is running on Xbox. Hence I have an exception at the following statement:

var controller = Gamepad.Gamepads.First();

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: I have been getting an exception of type "System.InvalidOperationException" in System.Linq.dll when I use Gamepad.Gamepads.First() in the MainPage method in MainPage.xaml.cs

Comment: It means, your controller is not visible for application. If you connect it to PC and your UWP app in PC - does it work?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the thumbsticks but you can detect the gamepad buttons as any other key press event.

Just hook into the `KeyUp` event of you page or to the global `Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyUp` event and check for the gamepad buttons like `VirtualKey.GamepadB`.

This works when the app runs on XBox One and also when you connect the XBox One controller to your PC using a USB cable.

Comment: The D-pad and thumbsticks fire keyup events as well. You can see the actual keycodes for each here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TVHelpers/blob/master/tvjs/src/DirectionalNavigation/directionalnavigation-1.0.0.0.js#L701

Comment: Thanks, this is much easier to use than polling the Gamepad readings.