# How to detect game controller button presses (ABXY) in UWP apps

Tags: c#, uwp, xbox-one

I've developed a UWP app that could potentially run on XBOX.

I want to detect whether the buttons on the gamepad controller have been pressed (either A B X or Y).

I think I need to be using the click event? If it is on the click event, what do I need to check in the click event?

Looking at this post which determines whether a trigger has been pressed..

[Controller support for Xbox one in Windows UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977767/controller-support-for-xbox-one-in-windows-uwp)

```
/*
 * Note: I have not tested this code.
 * If it is incorrect, please do edit with the fix.
 */
using Windows.Gaming.Input;

// bla bla bla boring stuff...

// Get the first controller
var controller = Gamepad.Gamepads.First();

// Get the current state
var reading = controller.GetCurrentReading();

// Check to see if the left trigger was depressed about half way down
if (reading.LeftTrigger == 0.5;)
{
    // Do whatever
}
```

I presume there is an equivalent way of checking whether one of the ABXY buttons have been pressed?. I shall check next time I get chance.

On another note, this blog post looks really useful for people starting out with developing UWP for Xbox One http://grogansoft.com/blog/?p=1278

**Update :** 
Looks like I can call GetCurrentReading() to get a [GamepadReading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.gaming.input.gamepadreading.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) structure. and from that get the state of the [GamepadButtons](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.gaming.input.gamepadbuttons.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

The `KeyDown` event from `CoreWindow` or any other UWP control will be fired even when user clicks the gamepad buttons. You can find values such as `GamepadA` and `GamepadB` in the [`VirtualKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.system.virtualkey.aspx) enumeration so basic method for checking their pressing could look like this:

```
private void CoreWindow_KeyDown(CoreWindow sender, KeyEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Handled)
    {
        return;
    }

    switch (args.VirtualKey)
    {
        case VirtualKey.GamepadA:
            // Gamepad A button was pressed
            break;

        case VirtualKey.GamepadB:
            // Gamepad B button was pressed
            break;

        case VirtualKey.GamepadX:
            // Gamepad X button was pressed
            break;

        case VirtualKey.GamepadY:
            // Gamepad Y button was pressed
            break;
    }
}
```

You have to subscribe the event (for example in constructor):

```
Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown += CoreWindow_KeyDown;
```

Comment: Hmm ok. I'll try that as well. Which of mine or your approaches is the generally accepted one? (I've still not tested my approach yet).

Comment: I think your approach is too complicated for just getting the info whether the button were tapped. It will be more useful in games and such things I think..

Comment: I'm wondering if that worked for the xbox as it required inclusion of the Window.System lib